# drawable image button size for ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi

Tags: android, drawable

I was search on the web long time, but problem is I'm not getting the original size for image button

I know this ratio

```
ldpi is 0.75x dimensions of mdpi
hdpi is 1.5x dimensions of mdpi
xhdpi is 2x dimensinons of mdpi
```

So can I take any standard of size of mdpi or anything else.

Comment: The answer is... whatever you see fit. Possibly, try using **dp** as you measure unit. Or simply use wrap_content or match_parent.

Comment: that means If i use 300*300 button then select wrap_content , it will not look perfectly.

Comment: If you want to use a pixel image, then your reference is the **mdpi** density, in which, `1px = 1dp`. then you have to prepare an **hdpi** (1.5x = 450px x 450px) version of your image, and so on **for all the supported densities** and use `300dp` as your dimensions. Possibly, start in your graphics program with the bigger density images and scale **down**, for a better image quality.